# Is it possible to list only updated podcasts in iTunes when looking in the AppStore? Alternatives?

Tags: iphone, itunes, podcasts, mac-app-store

I don't know if it's just me or what but finding podcasts on iTunes seems horrible.  I come across many podcasts that I think sound cool or interesting but then realize they haven't been updated since 2008!  Is there any way to make iTunes not list podcasts that have not been updated in the last 3 months?

Is there a better solution for finding podcasts outside of iTunes AppStore?

Love my iphone and love podcasts but I hate the iTunes interface for discovery :(

Answer (score 1):

Use Google or some other web source to research podcasts. Once you find the ones you want to subscribe to, you can do it direct from your browser (i think itunes is  usually one of the options whenever there is an RSS/podcast subscribe option. If not you could also copy the podcast feed URL and then in iTunes go to Advanced->Subscribe to Podcast..., and paste the URL in there.